# Local Storage Managing. Delete items one by one using .map() and .splice(), Or Clear All and insert new updated Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Practicing on developing To-do list using React.

Now I'am at the point when have to arrange a deleting tasks, one by one.

This is how I achieved it:

```js
handleDeleteTask(id) {
  const remainingTasks = this.state.tasks.filter(task => id !== task.id);
  this.setState({ tasks: remainingTasks });
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem('storageTasks', JSON.stringify(remainingTasks));
}
```

Basicaly I have got remaining tasks filtering tasks from state, and updating state.
To update tasks in Local storage I managed to clear all and insert a new Updated Array.

Will it be more efficient to use the `map()` and `slice()` method to eliminate just  needed object and not replacing an Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be more efficient to use `map()` method and `slice()` to eliminate just needed object and not replacing an Array?

It doesn't matter, because you aren't allowed to modify the array in state directly anyway. (Even if you could, it really wouldn't matter unless the array is **huge**, and it would be hard for us to say whether to would be better or worse without seeing the code. It isn't immediately clear why `map` would be involved, for instance.) So your `filter` approach is mostly correct.

There is a problem with it, though: Whenever you're updating state based on existing state, you have to use the *callback* form of `setState`, not the one you pass a new value to directly:

```
handleDeleteTask(id) {
    this.setState(({tasks}) => {
        tasks = tasks.filter(task => id !== task.id);
        // localStorage.clear(); // You probably don't need or want this
        localStorage.setItem("storageTasks", JSON.stringify(remainingTasks));
        return {tasks};
    });
}
```